# Typescript: Typing if a parameter contains a field

Tags: typescript

I have the below function I'm trying to type without using `any`.

```
export function byMostRecent(arr: any[]) {
  return [...arr].sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();
  })
}
```

I'm not sure how to say, "the parameter must contain a `createdAt` field".

Comment: That's what interfaces are for. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: Can you create an interface that has a field `createdAt` and use that instead of any. That ensures that members of `arr` must have `createdAt` field.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @JBNizet and kimobrian254. The problem is I have 10+ interfaces with createdAt.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You just need one more: { createdAt: number; }. All the 10 others will de facto extend this new one if they indeed have a createdAt field (although it would be better to make that explicit). Again, read the documentation.

Comment: @kimobrian254 is correct. You should specify the type of the element type of the array and not the argument to the callback. Typing the callback argument rather than the array is unidiomatic, confusing, and unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an interface (or as I will use below an anonymous type) and generics to constrain the argument type and to flow type information from argument to result:

```
export function byMostRecent<T extends { createdAt: string|number|Date }>(arr: T[]):T[] {
  return [...arr].sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();
  })
}
```

Comment: Very nice, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. very helpful.

Comment: One minor nitpick, it's not an anonymous interface, it's a type. Not a big deal but the allowed members and semantics are different. The inline type you have here could be, for example, a mapped type and extending it, with say a local type, would be different

Comment: @AluanHaddad better ? :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `createdAt` type:

```
interface Dates {
  createdAt: string|number|Date
}
export function byMostRecent(arr: Dates[]) {
  return [...arr].sort((a,b) => {
    return new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kimobrian254. If I pass in a non-`Dates` interface into `byMostRecent` it will emit an error. (E.X. `Project` is not assigned to type `Dates`)

Comment: @DanielRasmuson typescript has a structural type system. An array of anything with a `createdAt` property  will naturally be accepted by the functions interface, anything without that property will not be accepted.

Comment: Yeah, it will show an error definitely, createdAt must be a date. If you want anything just change the type of createdAt to any inside the interface.

Comment: @DanielRasmuson that's the whole point of typing. Passing Projects, which don't have a createdAt field, is an error. And it's a good thing that TypeScript doesn't allow doing that.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.